# How to parse string dates with 2-digit year?

Tags: python, date, y2k, 2-digit-year

I need to parse strings representing 6-digit dates in the format `yymmdd` where `yy` ranges from 59 to 05 (1959 to 2005). According to the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module docs, Python's default pivot year is 1969 which won't work for me.

Is there an easy way to override the pivot year, or can you suggest some other solution? I am using Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'd use `datetime` and parse it out normally.  Then I'd use `datetime.datetime.replace` on the object if it is past your ceiling date -- Adjusting it back 100 yrs.:

```
import datetime
dd = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%y%m%d')
if dd.year > 2005:
   dd = dd.replace(year=dd.year-100)
```

Comment: Note that `000229` would raise an error because `2100/02/29` does not exist, even though `2000/02/29` exists.

Answer (score 7):

Prepend the century to your date using your own pivot:

```
  year = int(date[0:2])
  if 59 <= year <= 99:
      date = '19' + date
  else
      date = '20' + date
```

and then use `strptime` with the `%Y` directive instead of `%y`.

Comment: There is a missing ':' after the else statement when using Py3.

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime
date = '20-Apr-53'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime( date, '%d-%b-%y' )
if dt.year > 2000:
    dt = dt.replace( year=dt.year-100 )
                     ^2053   ^1953
print dt.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also perform the following:

```
today=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
today=today[:-4]+today[-2:]
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently had a similar case, ended up with this basic calculation and logic:

```
pivotyear = 1969
century = int(str(pivotyear)[:2]) * 100

def year_2to4_digit(year):
    return century + year if century + year > pivotyear else (century + 100) + year
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with very recent dates as well as very old dates and want to use the current date as a pivot (not just the current year), try this code:

```py
import datetime
def parse_date(date_str):
    parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,'%y%m%d')
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if parsed > current_date:
        parsed = parsed.replace(year=parsed.year - 100)
    return parsed
```