# Python strptime parsing year without century: assume prior to this year?

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing some datetime strings in Python 2.7, using `datetime.strptime`. I want to assume that a date is prior to now.

But strptime's [`%y` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) does not do this by default:

```
d = '10/12/68'
n = datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%y')
print n
2068-12-10 00:00:00
```

Is there any way I can get Python to assume that `68` is `1968`, as it would be in common usage?

Or should I just parse the string and insert `19` or `20`, as appropriate, manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse string dates with 2-digit year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600548/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-2-digit-year)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easy to fix after the fact:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.strptime(...)
if dt > datetime.now():
    dt -= timedelta(years=100)
```

Comment: Thanks! `timedelta` doesn't accept a `years` argument, so I used `dt -= relativedelta(years=100)`. The required import is `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`.

Comment: Or: `timedelta(days=365)`, although this may not be as safe because of leap years..

Comment: `dt = dt.replace(year=dt.year-100)`

Comment: @iliyesku Also not safe. Raises if dt is xxxx/02/29.

Answer (score 5):

If your input is in the local timezone:

```
from datetime import date

then = datetime.strptime('10/12/68', '%d/%m/%y').date()
if date.today() <= then: # *then* must be in the past
    then = then.replace(year=then.year - 100)
```

It should work ok until 2100 (excluding). See here for [more details on arithmetic with calendar years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658742/4279).