# Pandas to_datetime changes year unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a date column which after using pandas `read_csv` is represented as the object type. I'm trying to convert it to pandas datetime object but when using `pd.to_datetime()` it returns incorrect datetime object.

for example, I have dates in this format `01-06-68`, where 01 is the day, 06 is the month and 68 is the year. Applying pandas `to_datetime()` to this string returns `2068-06-01` but should return `1968-06-01`, where 06 is a month and 01 is the day.

I tried every possible solution using pandas to_datetime(), python's datetime, pendulum library but still getting an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strptime parsing year without century: assume prior to this year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407127/python-strptime-parsing-year-without-century-assume-prior-to-this-year)

Comment: So it seems that anything with the %y year below 69 will be attributed a century of 2000, and 69 upwards get 1900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[:-2] + '19' + df['date'].str[-2:])
```

Another solution with `replace`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace(r'-(\d+)$', r'-19\1'))
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
       date
0  01-06-70
1  01-06-69
2  01-06-68
3  01-06-67

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace(r'-(\d+)$', r'-19\1'))
print (df)
        date
0 1970-01-06
1 1969-01-06
2 1968-01-06
3 1967-01-06
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a `format=` parameter in [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
You can probably try `df['my_col'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%d-%m-%Y')`

See other way to do it here: [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)