# Convert dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am facing issues when converting a date from dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy with pandas.

I have tried this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

But somehow for some values the day and month are swapping...
Is there another way to convert correctly?

Thanks in advance for answering me :)

Comment: The bug is using a string instead of an actual `datetime` and a two-digit year localized format at that. Where does the data come from? The best option is to properly handle the date while loading. `read_csv` allows you to specify the date string format. Loading from Excel or databases shouldn't have any problems because both have strongly typed dates

Comment: There's no way even a human can guess what `xx/xx/xx` means, You need to specify the pattern through the `format` parameter, eg `to_datetime(..,format='%d/%m/%y')` or at least setting the `dateFirst` to `True`. All possible combinations can return a valid date in one locale or another, even *multiple* dates. 1930 and 2030 are both `30` in that unfortunate format. A better solution though is to ensure you either load valid dates from your source, or use the unambiguous ISO8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you probably meant the `dayfisrt` switch instead of `datefirst`. Agreed `xx/xx/xxxx` or even worse `xx/xx/xx` is undecidable in many case and without a convention on day and year. But here the convention is known. Anyway keeping trouble away it is better to use ISO 8601 or RFC 3339 format when exporting timestamps in text format.

Comment: @jlandercy known to whom? [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html). And in January 2020, the big IT news was how [Lloyd's and other banks](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) crashed for days because their hacky Y2K fixes simply appended `19` in from of two-digit years above 20.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is why it is undecidable without a convention or a standardized exchange format. The OP probably needs the `dayfirst` switch or to enforce the format to recovers its data as you mentioned and then day and month will not be messed up as long as its data follow the format he stated in its post title. In this case which seems to be the case when reading its post again: the convention will be sufficient to recover the data. And indeed it is better to use ISO 8061 or RFC 3339 to exchange. We are saying the same thing here. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Version**

You can specify the `format` but that doesn't mean there won't be any problems due to the Y2K bug inherent in two-digit years

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d/%m/%y')
```

The string `'10/12/68'` will be parsed as December 10, 2068.

If possible, get whoever creates this value to use the unambiguous ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`

**Long Explanation**

The correct way is to simply not use such strings. There's no way even a human could guess what `xx/xx/xx` means. What does `12/5/12` mean? December 5 or May 12? 1912 or 2012? How about `10/12/68`?

This isn't nitpicking. Such bugs are still causing serious problems even now:

- [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html) September 2020
- [Y2K? How about Y2.02K as Lloyds suffers its second TITSUP* of the year](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) January 2020
- [Y2K quick-fix crick? 1920s come roaring back after mystery blip at UK's vehicle licensing agency](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/) January 2020

The real fix is to modify the application that generates such dates to use the unambiguous YYYY-MM-DD format, or use a source that has strongly-typed dates. For example Excel and almost all databases have date types.

**Workarounds**

When that's not possible, you need to specify the date pattern using the `format` parameter.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d/%m/%y')
```

There's still a chance for errors though, because the two-digit year will get translated based on a cutoff rule.

For example [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407127/python-strptime-parsing-year-without-century-assume-prior-to-this-year) `'10/12/68'` was parsed as `2068-12-10` instead of `1968`:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('10/12/68', '%d/%m/%y')
datetime.datetime(2068, 12, 10, 0, 0)
```

Oops