# How to force assumption of past dates when year is ambiguous

Tags: python, datetime

I have dates in DD/MM/YY format, where year is ambiguous. These are recorded dates so will always be in the past.

At the time of writing, a date for '69 is correctly interpreted as 1969:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('01/06/69','%d/%m/%y')
datetime.datetime(1969, 1, 1, 0, 6)
```

However, dates in '68 are being interpreted as 2068:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('01/06/68','%d/%m/%y')
datetime.datetime(2068, 1, 1, 0, 6)
```

Is there an option in `datetime` to force assumption that dates are in the past?

Comment: There's no reasonable way to automate this because, as you say, these 2-digit years are ambiguous. They could mean, for example, 1868. How would you ever know?

Comment: But You can actually write a costume function to format the date. I think

Comment: I agree with what @Pingu is saying - however, if you are only struggling between the 20th and 21st centuries (or a limited set)- maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407127/python-strptime-parsing-year-without-century-assume-prior-to-this-year

Comment: You probably mean '%d/%m/%y' as format string

Comment: @Pingu I believe that in the context of short form year in datetime strptime function, the only options are the 20th and 21st century.

Comment: @Mortz thanks for the link, that is indeed the same question. However that's for Python2 so I'll leave this one up for now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, this is expected behaviour as described in datetime documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/time.html

> Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code.
> When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the
> POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and
> values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.

What I would recommend you is using %Y to remove the ambiguity

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('01/06/1967','%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(1967, 6, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fix the date afterwards

```
from datetime import datetime
_now = datetime.now()
fix_date = lambda dt: dt if dt < _now else datetime(dt.year - 100, dt.month,
                       dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond)

print(fix_date(datetime.strptime('01/06/68','%d/%m/%y')))
```

But in the end you are just moving the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You say that none of your dates are in the future. You also imply that anything that "looks like" a future date should actually be in the previous century.

That being the case then you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def fixdate(ds):
    d = datetime.strptime(ds, '%d/%m/%y')
    if d > datetime.now():
        d -= timedelta(days=36525)
    return d

dates = ['09/11/68', '09/11/69']

for date in dates:
    print(fixdate(date))
```

**Output:**

```
1968-11-09 00:00:00
1969-11-09 00:00:00
```

Comment: No "looks like" necessary - `datetime` knows which dates are in the future at runtime.

Comment: @otocan By "visually" I mean, for example, '09/11/67'