# Convert string array to datetime array

Tags: python, datetime

If I needed to convert a string to a date object, but the dates weren't formatted the correct way, how would I do that?

For example, if I needed to convert `'3/10/18'` or `'11/7/18'` to a date so I could append it to a new array, what method should I use?

I tried `datetime.strptime(string, '%m/%d/%Y')`, but since the month or date isn't always 2 digits in the string, it won't convert it.

Comment: That is a problem indeed, do you know if the day's always first? Otherwise how can you know if 1/4/2000 is 1st of April or 4th of Jan?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse string dates with 2-digit year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600548/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-2-digit-year)

Answer (score 3):

As described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html):

> When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %J, %U, %W, and %V. Format %y does require a leading zero

The leading zero is optional for formats `%d` and `%m`. The problem is the `%Y` which needs a complete year. If you want the two-character year, use `%y`:

```
from datetime import datetime

l =  ['3/10/18', '11/7/18']

[datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%y') for s in l]
# [datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 7, 0, 0)]
```