# datetime.datetime.strptime Incorrect year converting (with "%y" format)

Tags: python, datetime

When I trying a such date all working finely

`datetime.datetime.strptime('4/20/69', '%m/%d/%y').date()`
`# according to the docs: %y Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.`

I got

`datetime.date(1969, 4, 20)`

But when I'm trying a such date (year = 50)

`datetime.datetime.strftime('4/20/50', '%m/%d/%y').date()`

I got

`datetime.date(2050, 4, 20)`

So why I got year = 2050 instead of 1950? There any additional docs or paramters to get get correct year (all values lower 2000 converting to 19xx) ?

Comment: 2-digit year in datetime will lead to ambiguities, don't use it. You encountered an example why.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16600548/10197418