# Convert string date (25-Aug-47) to y-m-d date (1947-08-25)

Tags: python, datetime, converters

I have a column of Date in a Dataframe where the dates are written in this format -

```
No.  Date
0    25-Aug-47
1    16-Sep-48
2    03-Oct-49
```

I want to convert the values of Date Column into this format -

```
No.  Date
0    1947-08-25
1    1948-09-16
2    1949-10-03
```

first, I tried to do this -

```
df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

but this statement gives me this answer -

```
No.  Date
0    2047-08-25
1    2048-09-16
2    2049-10-03
```

then again I tried this -

```
def mdy_to_ymd(d):
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%y-%m-%d')

for i in df['Date']:
    mdy_to_ymd(i)
```

this statement gives me this answer -

```
No.  Date
0    47-08-25
1    48-09-16
2    49-10-03
```

Comment: Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600548/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-2-digit-year), and the format your dates in the usual fashion.

Comment: have you tried .strftime('19%y-%m-%d') ? might be a quick hack

Comment: @Timus Thanks that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @OctaviodelSer Thank you for suggestion but I also have some 21th century years in the columns that's why this won't work.